# Material Radio Label Content Wont Apply Text Wrap CSS Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a radio group with a fixed width and I would like the button labels to wrap. I have tried adding classes to every part of the html and adding "white-space: normal" to the elements but it just ignores it. How can I make it work?

[Here is an example of where I am at](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1shnoa)

If I add this CSS to the top level styles.scss file it works as intended.

```
.mat-radio-label-content {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

But I want to avoid this and keep the css only relevant to the specific component and not app wide.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Wrap your label text in a span with a selector.

```
    <style>
        .wrap-mat-radio-label {
            white-space: normal;
        }
    </style>

    <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button>     
            <span class="wrap-mat-radio-label">
                {{ season }}
            </span>
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Thanks you, very helpful! Do you know why the `.mat-radio-label-content` doesn't accept the CSS?

Comment: @Maverick283 It's because the element `.mat-radio-label-content` is scoped and not a part of your component. But you can set this style like `.mat-radio-label-content { white-space: normal; }` in your global styles like `styles.scss`. Then it works. But be careful with global styles. It's better to be explicit than implicit here. Means you could create a custom selector here like `mat-radio-group.text-wrap` and then access the `.mat-radio-label-content` to set the wrap option.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution with global styles (e.g. `styles.scss`).

**The simple brute solution:**

```css
.mat-radio-label-content {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

But be careful with global styles. We should add a custom class selector to avoid global unintended issues.

**Custom class selector:**

```css
mat-radio-group.text-wrap {
  .mat-radio-label-content {
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

Why not `text-wrap` on `mat-radio-button`? Because Angular Material overrides all classes on that element. Also the class to the `mat-radio-group` gives us more options (see below) and is less to write.

**Even more polishing:**

```css
mat-radio-group.text-wrap {
  /* Add some space between the options for readability. */
  /* Especially when we align the radio symbol on start position. */
  gap: 2px;

  .mat-radio-container {
    /* The default behavior is center. */
    /* But the radio options are then difficult to tell apart. */
    /* Therefore we align the radio symbol on top position. */
    align-self: start;
  }

  .mat-radio-label-content {
    /* Wrap the label text. */
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

(StackOverflow has no highlighting for SCSS. Therefore it's a CSS block. Therefore the comment styles. If someone wondering... Trivia: In SCSS you should prefer `//` comments that will be removed on build. `/**/` stays in build.)

Feel free to go your own way. The stage is yours. You could also try nagging the Angular Material developers to officially provide a text wrapping feature to avoid custom "hacking". But in my experience, they strictly adhere to the Material Guidelines. Even if it means an improvement, they are difficult to persuade. You could also consider to switch the UI Framework.